# Linear regression to clean data not working in a data frame in R

Tags: r, error-handling, dataframe, na, model-fitting

I am having trouble with cleaning a data frame after I assign some NA's to certain values. First I have a data.frame called credit_clean which has no NA's in it. It looks like this.

```
str(credit_clean)
'data.frame':   150000 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ default       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ age           : int  45 40 38 30 49 74 57 39 27 57 ...
 $ debtratio     : num  0.803 0.1219 0.0851 0.036 0.0249 ...
 $ balance_limits: num  0.766 0.957 0.658 0.234 0.907 ...
 $ loans         : int  6 0 0 0 1 1 3 0 0 4 ...
 $ past60_90     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Then I assign NA's to outliers, in different columns of the df.

```
credit_clean$balance_limits[credit_clean$balance_limits >= 5] <- NA
credit_clean$debtratio[credit_clean$debtratio >= 5] <- NA
credit_clean$loans[credit_clean$loans >= 15] <- NA
```

I created a new df called credit_cl with the NA values removed. The new df has 120005 observations and no NA's again.

```
credit_cl <- credit_clean[complete.cases(credit_clean), ]
str(credit_cl)
'data.frame':   120005 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ default       : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ age           : int  45 40 38 30 49 74 39 57 30 51 ...
 $ debtratio     : num  0.803 0.1219 0.0851 0.036 0.0249 ...
 $ balance_limits: num  0.766 0.957 0.658 0.234 0.907 ...
 $ loans         : int  6 0 0 0 1 1 0 4 0 2 ...
 $ past60_90     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

The problem comes here, when I try to fit and predict using a linear regression, it does nothing, does not even show an error. I also have this problem when trying to use an information value function called iv.mult(), from the library(woe).

```
library(woe)
iv.mult(credit_cl,"default", summary = TRUE)
```

R does nothing then, so I don't know were the mistake is happening, since the data frame seems like any other df I have used.

Im using R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk" with RStudio Version 0.99.891

Comment: That's a pretty big dataset. Is it possible it's just running slowly?